# Add a video control on top of a local html video

Tags: javascript, video

The following is a link which shows a nice example of playing a **local** video in a browser:

http://jsfiddle.net/dsbonev/cCCZ2/

```
<h1>HTML5 local video file player example</h1>
<div id="message"></div>
<input type="file" accept="video/*"/>
<video controls autoplay></video>
```

However, on top of this, I would like to allow the user to create a "trailer clip" of a particular segment of their video. In this, I would like to have some sort of adjustable playhead such as the following:

[image]

Here is a site that does this exact same thing: https://www.flexclip.com/editor/app?ratio=landscape. Any insight into how I would go about building something like this that plays the local file and allows me to select a segment of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few different things, though the particular question seems to be how to draw a preview bar of a local video.

#### Local Files

From the example in your question, you can see it's not too different working with a local file than with a remote file; you can create an object URL of the local file via `URL.createObjectURL` and then work with it as you would a normal video link.

#### Drawing the Preview Bar

Drawing the preview bar should consist of seeking to the appropriate time in the video, and then drawing that frame onto a canvas. You can seek to a specific point by setting the `.currentTime` property of the video and waiting for the `seeked` event. You can then use the *canvasContext*`.drawImage` method to draw an image using the video element.

I'd also recommend using a video element that isn't attached to the DOM for this, for a better user experience that doesn't have an onscreen video jumping to different times.

It could look something like this:

```
function goToTime(video, time) {
  return new Promise ((resolve) => {
    function cb () {
      video.removeEventListener('seeked', cb);
      resolve();
    }
    video.addEventListener('seeked', cb);
    video.currentTime = time;
  });
}

async function drawPreviewBar(video) {
  const { duration, videoWidth, videoHeight } = video;
  const previewBarFrameWidth = previewBarHeight  * videoWidth / videoHeight;
  const previewBarFrames = previewBarWidth / previewBarFrameWidth;
  for (let i = 0; i < previewBarFrames; i++) {
    await goToTime(video, i * duration * previewBarFrameWidth / previewBarWidth);
    previewBarContext.drawImage(video, 0, 0,
      videoWidth, videoHeight,
      previewBarFrameWidth * i, 0,
      previewBarFrameWidth, previewBarHeight
    );
  }
}
```

#### Resizing / Moving the Selected Clip

If you want to create a UI to resize or move around the clip, you can use standard drag handlers.

#### Example

Here's a basic example:

```js
const previewBarWidth = 600;
const previewBarHeight = 40;
const videoElement = document.getElementById('video');
const inputElement = document.getElementById('file-picker');
const invisibleVideo = document.createElement('video');
const previewBarCanvas = document.getElementById('preview-bar-canvas');
previewBarCanvas.width = previewBarWidth;
previewBarCanvas.height = previewBarHeight;
const selector = document.getElementById('selector');
const previewBarContext = previewBarCanvas.getContext('2d');
const topHandle = document.getElementById('selector-top-handle');
const leftHandle = document.getElementById('selector-left-handle');
const rightHandle = document.getElementById('selector-right-handle');
const leftMask = document.getElementById('selector-left-mask');
const rightMask = document.getElementById('selector-right-mask');

var selectorLeft = 0, selectorWidth = previewBarWidth;
var minimumPreviewBarWidth = 80; // may want to dynamically change this based on video duration
var videoLoaded = false;

function goToTime(video, time) {
  return new Promise ((resolve) => {
    function cb () {
      video.removeEventListener('seeked', cb);
      resolve();
    }
    video.addEventListener('seeked', cb);
    video.currentTime = time;
  });
}

async function drawPreviewBar(video) {
  const { duration, videoWidth, videoHeight } = video;
  const previewBarFrameWidth = previewBarHeight  * videoWidth / videoHeight;
  const previewBarFrames = previewBarWidth / previewBarFrameWidth;
  for (let i = 0; i < previewBarFrames; i++) {
    await goToTime(video, i * duration * previewBarFrameWidth / previewBarWidth);
    previewBarContext.drawImage(video, 0, 0, videoWidth, videoHeight, previewBarFrameWidth * i, 0, previewBarFrameWidth, previewBarHeight);
  }
}

function loadVideo(file) {
  var src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  var loaded = new Promise(function (resolve) {
    invisibleVideo.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', resolve);
  }).then(function () {
    videoLoaded = true;
    document.body.classList.add('loaded');
    return drawPreviewBar(invisibleVideo);
  });
  videoElement.src = src;
  invisibleVideo.src = src;
  return loaded;
}

function updateSelectorBar() {
  selector.style.width = selectorWidth + 'px';
  selector.style.left = selectorLeft + 'px';
  leftMask.style.width = selectorLeft + 'px';
  rightMask.style.left = (selectorLeft + selectorWidth) + 'px';
  rightMask.style.width = (previewBarWidth - selectorWidth - selectorLeft) + 'px';
}

function selectorUpdated() {
  if (!videoLoaded) {
    return;
  }
  var startFraction = selectorLeft / previewBarWidth;
  var durationFraction = selectorWidth / previewBarWidth;
  var startTime = startFraction * invisibleVideo.duration;
  var duration = durationFraction * invisibleVideo.duration;
  var endTime = startTime + duration;
  // do something with startTime, endTime, and duration, maybe;
  videoElement.currentTime = startTime;
}

function addDragHandler (event, cb, ecb) {
  var startX = event.clientX;
  function dragged(e) {
    cb(e.clientX - startX);
  }
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', dragged);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', function ended() {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', dragged);
    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', ended);
    ecb();
  });
}

updateSelectorBar();
topHandle.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
  var startLeft = selectorLeft;
  addDragHandler(e, function (dx) {
    selectorLeft = Math.max(0, Math.min(previewBarWidth - selectorWidth, startLeft + dx));
    updateSelectorBar();
  }, selectorUpdated);
});

leftHandle.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
  var startLeft = selectorLeft;
  var startWidth = selectorWidth;
  addDragHandler(e, function (dx) {
    selectorLeft = Math.max(0, Math.min(selectorLeft + selectorWidth - minimumPreviewBarWidth, startLeft + dx));
    selectorWidth = (startWidth + startLeft - selectorLeft);
    updateSelectorBar();
  }, selectorUpdated);
});

rightHandle.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
  var startWidth = selectorWidth;
  addDragHandler(e, function (dx) {
    selectorWidth = Math.max(minimumPreviewBarWidth, Math.min(previewBarWidth - selectorLeft, startWidth + dx));
    updateSelectorBar();
  }, selectorUpdated);
});

var pendingLoad = Promise.resolve();
inputElement.addEventListener('change', function () {
  let file = inputElement.files[0];
  pendingLoad = pendingLoad.then(function () {
   return loadVideo(file)
  });
});
```

```css
#video {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#preview-bar {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.canvas-container {
  position: relative;
  left: 5px;
}

#preview-bar-canvas {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;

}

#selector {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  border-left-width: 5px;
  border-right-width: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: show;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.loaded #selector{
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: initial;
}

#selector-top-handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-100%);
  background: darkgreen;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  cursor: move;
}

.resize-handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 5px;
  cursor: ew-resize;
  background: darkgreen;
  opacity: 0.75;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.resize-handle:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.preview-mask {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.6;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#selector-left-mask {
  left: 0;
}

#selector-left-handle {
  left: -5px;
}
#selector-right-handle {
  right: -5px;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file-picker" />
<video id="video"></video>
<div id="preview-bar">
  <div class="canvas-container">
    <canvas id="preview-bar-canvas"></canvas>
    <div id="selector-left-mask" class="preview-mask"></div>
    <div id="selector-right-mask" class="preview-mask"></div>
  </div>
  <div id ="selector">
     <div id="selector-top-handle"></div>
     <div id="selector-left-handle" class="resize-handle"></div>
     <div id="selector-right-handle" class="resize-handle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sure thing-- let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 0):

Here is some infomation I found online about this question:
(all of the lines are commented fyi)

https://gist.github.com/simonhaenisch/116010ed657f6b257246464e33719613

Comment: sure, but what does that have to do with what I asked?

Comment: @David542 it runs a local video in the browser but it also allows you to skip ahead and change the playback speed. It was the closest I could get to helping you

Comment: got it, well anyways I appreciate your time, but not quite what I'm looking for.